# Shares accepted by pool but no due XMR

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, mining

I am using XMRig CPU miner which is working fine. I am getting 1.2-1.3 kh/s on CPU. I got the wallet set up via Monero wallet. I use the usxmrpool. When I check my wallet address on the pool, I see my accepted shares, but not XMR due payments. How can that be?

Answer (score 1):

Your pending balance will start showing once the blocks you have worked on have matured. ~60 new blocks found on the network.

Comment: Thanks Dave. So at some point all the shares will be recognized as due payments. What does it mean for a block to mature?

Comment: At some point the shares will be gone and converted to the actual balance. But do not expect that shares are equal to the balance. block maturing basically means that a block is found. After a block is found by your pool and get's accepted, you're balance will increase